# How to redirect the output of an application in background to /dev/null

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to redirect the output generated from a background application in Linux to /dev/null.

I am using kate text editor and it prints all the debug messages on the terminal which I would like to redirect to /dev/null.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look a this page. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You use:

```
yourcommand  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If it should run in the Background add an `&`

```
yourcommand > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`>/dev/null 2>&1` means redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` AND `stderr` to the place where `stdout` points at that time

If you want `stderr` to occur on console and only `stdout` going to `/dev/null` you can use:

```
yourcommand 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

In this case `stderr` is redirected to `stdout` (e.g. your console) and *afterwards* the original `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null`

If the program should not terminate you can use:

```
nohup yourcommand &
```

Without any parameter all output lands in nohup.out

Comment: both work, but there is a slight difference, but don't remeber

Comment: ah ok got it and added the other version

Comment: If this is the last command in a bash file, one thing that I noticed is that it leaves the command console that called the file without a prompt.

Comment: @elig redirecting output of an already running application is not possible imo, or at least not that easily, because the redirection via `dup2()` happens immediately after `fork()` but before `exec*()`. Once `exec*()` has executed the program, the shell has not the capability to redirect the output of that process. Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't know about a shell that has implemented such functionality.

Comment: What is the difference between `yourcommand 2>&1 > /dev/null` and `yourcommand > /dev/null`? Both seem to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: both commands you mentioned do only redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` and leave `stderr` to output on the current console. They are semantically the same and where just used to give an example. Note that in both cases `stderr` ist **not** reditected to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 12):

These will also redirect both:

```
yourcommand  &> /dev/null

yourcommand  >& /dev/null
```

though the bash manual says the first is preferred.

Comment: The manual and preference referred to is found here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html (at section 3.6.4)