# HTTP server shut down after running for some time

Tags: httpserver

I'm starting an http server(npm package installed globally) on Centos 7 using the command below. The server runs fine for some time but after that it goes down automatically not sure what is causing this.

`sudo nohup http-server -p 8081 >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

I need to make sure server never goes down.
Any help would be appreciated around how to debug this issue.

I am also fine with any other better way to run stable http server using command prompt.

Comment: Do you close your terminal after that?

Comment: This question/answer ([How to redirect the output of an application in background to /dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220098/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-an-application-in-background-to-dev-null)) shows how to get rid of al (possible) errors that occur in a script. In stead of redirecting to `/dev/null`, you could also redirect to a file, and look for errors/messages in that file.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, I close the terminal after that but that should not be an issue as I am using nohup, which will keep running this server in background.

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, I will try to log the out and check for logs. Let's see if I can find something.

Comment: Is this your local machine or a remote server?